# ggplot: Change order of bars in a single graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am quite new to R programming. I have encounterd an issue with my code I need to have fixed. I have looked for a solution but as I am quite new, I don't always understand the solutions given in other topics. Hope someone can help me out.

Issue:
I managed to save several 'plots' in a png file. As you can see in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjtBX.png), the bars in the third graph are reversed. This is mainly because there is no 'yes' in the dataset. I was able to solve this as you can probably see in the code.

Can someone explain to me how to adjust this so that the bars of the third graph are in the same order as the rest?

Code:

```
SL1 <- tibble(res = c(df$slachtoffer.1.[df$startvraag=="Ja"])) %>% 
  mutate(res = as.factor(res))
levels(SL1$res) <- c(levels(SL1$res),"Ja") 
SO1 <- ggplot(SL1, aes(x = res)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "Count", width = 0.9, fill = d) +
  ggtitle(title[8]) + ylab("") + xlab("") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        text=element_text(size=22, family="Open Sans"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 28, family="Open Sans"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 22, family="Open Sans"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  #plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,0,1), "in"))+
  #theme(aspect.ratio = 1.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 80, by = 10),
                     limits = c(0, 80),
                     expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1)))

SL2 <- tibble(res = c(df$slachtoffer.2.[df$startvraag=="Ja"])) %>% 
  mutate(res = as.factor(res))
levels(SL2$res) <- c(levels(SL2$res),"Ja") 
SO2 <- ggplot(SL2, aes(x = res)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "Count", width = 0.9, fill = d) +
  ggtitle(title[9]) + ylab("") + xlab("") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        text=element_text(size=22, family="Open Sans"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 28, family="Open Sans"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 22, family="Open Sans"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  #plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,0,1), "in"))+
  #theme(aspect.ratio = 1.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 80, by = 10),
                     limits = c(0, 80),
                     expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1)))

SL3 <- tibble(res = c(df$slachtoffer.3.[df$startvraag=="Ja"])) %>% 
  mutate(res = as.factor(res))
levels(SL3$res) <- c(levels(SL3$res),"Ja") 
SO3 <- ggplot(SL3, aes(x = res)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "Count", width = 0.9, fill = d) +
  ggtitle(title[10]) + ylab("") + xlab("") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        text=element_text(size=22, family="Open Sans"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 28, family="Open Sans"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 22, family="Open Sans"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  #plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,0,1), "in"))+
  #theme(aspect.ratio = 1.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 80, by = 10),
                     limits = c(0, 80),
                     expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1)))


SL4 <- tibble(res = c(df$slachtoffer.4.[df$startvraag=="Ja"])) %>% 
  mutate(res = as.factor(res))
levels(SL4$res) <- c(levels(SL4$res),"Ja") 
SO4 <- ggplot(SL4, aes(x = res)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "Count", width = 0.9, fill = d) +
  ggtitle(title[11]) + ylab("") + xlab("") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        text=element_text(size=22, family="Open Sans"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 28, family="Open Sans"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 22, family="Open Sans"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  #plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,0,1), "in"))+
  #theme(aspect.ratio = 1.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 80, by = 10),
                     limits = c(0, 80),
                     expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1)))

SL5 <- tibble(res = c(df$slachtoffer.5.[df$startvraag=="Ja"])) %>% 
  mutate(res = as.factor(res))
levels(SL5$res) <- c(levels(SL5$res),"Ja") 
SO5 <- ggplot(SL5, aes(x = res)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "Count", width = 0.9, fill = d) +
  ggtitle(title[12]) + ylab("") + xlab("") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        text=element_text(size=22, family="Open Sans"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 28, family="Open Sans"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 22, family="Open Sans"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  #plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,0,1), "in"))+
  #theme(aspect.ratio = 1.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 80, by = 10),
                     limits = c(0, 80),
                     expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1)))

SL6 <- tibble(res = c(df$slachtoffer.6.[df$startvraag=="Ja"])) %>% 
  mutate(res = as.factor(res))
levels(SL6$res) <- c(levels(SL6$res),"Ja") 
SO6 <- ggplot(SL6, aes(x = res)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "Count", width = 0.9, fill = d) +
  ggtitle(title[13]) + ylab("") + xlab("") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        text=element_text(size=22, family="Open Sans"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 28, family="Open Sans"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 22, family="Open Sans"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  #plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,0,1), "in"))+
  #theme(aspect.ratio = 1.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 80, by = 10),
                     limits = c(0, 80),
                     expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1)))

SL7 <- tibble(res = c(df$slachtoffer.7.[df$startvraag=="Ja"])) %>% 
  mutate(res = as.factor(res))
levels(SL7$res) <- c(levels(SL7$res),"Ja") 
SO7 <- ggplot(SL7, aes(x = res)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "Count", width = .9, fill = d) +
  ggtitle(title[14]) + ylab("") + xlab("") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        text=element_text(size=22, family="Open Sans"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 28, family="Open Sans"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 22, family="Open Sans"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
        #plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,0,1), "in"))+
  #theme(aspect.ratio = 1.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 80, by = 10),
                     limits = c(0, 80),
                     expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1)))


gA <- ggplotGrob(SO1)
gB <- ggplotGrob(SO2)
gC <- ggplotGrob(SO3)
gD <- ggplotGrob(SO4)
gE <- ggplotGrob(SO5)
gF <- ggplotGrob(SO6)
gG <- ggplotGrob(SO7)

maxWidth = grid::unit.pmax(gA$widths[2:4], gB$widths[2:4], gC$widths[2:4], gD$widths[2:4], gE$widths[2:4], gF$widths[2:4], gG$widths[2:4])
gA$widths[2:4] <- as.list(maxWidth)
gB$widths[2:4] <- as.list(maxWidth)
gC$widths[2:4] <- as.list(maxWidth)
gD$widths[2:4] <- as.list(maxWidth)
gE$widths[2:4] <- as.list(maxWidth)
gF$widths[2:4] <- as.list(maxWidth)
gG$widths[2:4] <- as.list(maxWidth)

test1 <- grid.arrange(
  gA, gB, gC, gD, gE, gF, gG,
  nrow = 1
)

ggsave("slachtoffer.png", 
       plot = test1, 
       device = "png", 
       scale = 1,
       width = 1000, 
       height = 300, 
       units = c("mm")
       )
```

Comment: Try using `arrange` beforehand, sorting by the vector that holds your answer key, e.g. `Ja/Nee`.

Comment: How would I implement this in the code? As I've mentioned I am quite new and I don't always understand the given solution, sorry @mhovd

Answer (score 0):

So after some adjustments I found the following: The mutate was changing all of the answers to Yes instead of No. By removing the mutate and changing the bar order it was fixed!

Code now looks like this:

```
SL3 <- tibble(res = c(df$slachtoffer.3.[df$startvraag=="Ja"]))
levels(SL3$res) <- c(levels(SL3$res))
SL3$res <- factor(SL3$res, levels = c("Ja", "Nee"))
SG3 <- ggplot(SL3, aes(x = res)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "Count", width = 0.9, fill = d) +
  ggtitle(title[10]) + ylab("") + xlab("") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        text=element_text(size=22, family="Open Sans"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 28, family="Open Sans"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 22, family="Open Sans"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  #plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,0,1), "in"))+
  #theme(aspect.ratio = 1.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 80, by = 10),
                     limits = c(0, 80),
                     expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1)))
```

At least this works for me :)